# How to make layout so images takes remaining height

Tags: css, image, layout, flexbox

I want to build this layout so my images, that are in 2nd and 3rd row take remaining space, to go all the way to first row. I just displayed flex and set flex-wrap: wrap. But that does not solve my problem. [image]  This is what i want

Comment: It's more close to the grid layout rather than the flexbox. use grid.

Comment: are these random images or are they always the same ratio ?

Comment: You could use `flex-direction: column`.

Comment: masonry is probably not needed if you already know the size/ratio of your images. they can be spanning through rows and be placed into columns. example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xxjEEOJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use column-count for the container of images check [here](https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/) for more info

```js
function getRandomSize(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

var allImages = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  var width = getRandomSize(200, 400);
  var height =  getRandomSize(200, 400);
  allImages += '<img src="https://placekitten.com/'+width+'/'+height+'?random='+i+'" alt="gallery photo">';
}

$('#photos').append(allImages);
```

```css
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;
   
   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  column-count:         4;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count:         3;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count:         2;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count:         1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="photos"></section>
```